# boost::asio server - detect failure to listen to server port

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a boost::asio based server which works fine, except that I'm trying to add a check that nothing else is accepting connections on the same port. If I create two of the servers, one of them consistently accepts the connections, but the other does not report any error ( which of the two accepts all connections appears to be random ).

The relevant bits of the server class ( it's a template which uses a base class which has Accepted() and typedefs for the connection type to create ) are:

```
        MessageServer ( boost::asio::io_service &io, unsigned short port_num )
            : BaseServerType ( io ), acceptor_ ( io, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ( boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port_num ) ) {
            Listen();
        }
        void Listen () {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            acceptor_.listen ( boost::asio::socket_base::max_connections, ec );

            if ( !ec ) {
                start_accept();
            } else {
                // not reached even if a separate process 
                // is already listening to that port
                connection_pointer new_connection;
                BaseServerType::Accepted ( new_connection );
            }
        }

    private:
        void start_accept() {
            connection_pointer new_connection ( CreateConnection ( acceptor_.io_service() ) );

            acceptor_.async_accept ( new_connection -> Socket(),
                                     boost::bind ( &MessageServer::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
                                                   boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
        }

        void handle_accept ( connection_pointer new_connection, const boost::system::error_code &error ) {
            if ( !error ) {
                BaseServerType::Accepted ( new_connection );
                new_connection -> Start();
                start_accept();
            } else {
                // never reached
                new_connection.reset();
                BaseServerType::Accepted ( new_connection );
            }
        }

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
```

acceptor.listen() doesn't throw either.

How is a failure to listen to a server port reported in boost::asio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` constructor you use has a default argument `reuse_address = true`. this sets SO_REUSEADDR socket option. disabling this option you'll receive error on `acceptor.listen()`. [more info about SO_REUSEADDR here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229860/what-is-the-meaning-of-so-reuseaddr-setsockopt-option-linux)

Be aware that this option is [treated differently on windows and linux](http://itamarst.org/writings/win32sockets.html)

Comment: If I translate above description, here is code.
MessageServer ( boost::asio::io_service &io, unsigned short port_num )
: BaseServerType ( io )
, acceptor_ ( io, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ( boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port_num, false ) ) {
  Listen();
}
...
try {
   server = new MessageServer(io_service_, 5000);
} catch (std::exception const&  ex)
{
   printf("bind error: %s\n", ex.what());
}

Comment: From the linked website: "On Windows it lets you bind to the same TCP port multiple times without errors. Verified experimentally by failing test, I never bothered to check out MSDN docs for this one, I just don't use it on Windows."

Answer (score 0):

The error you want would be [thrown or returned](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/bind/overload1.html) from `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::bind()`. The [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor/overload3.html) you are using will exhibit this same behavior, I suggest you boil your example down to something smaller that is reproducible. It is not obvious to me how you handle exceptions thrown from your `MessageServer` ctor.

Comment: As with any constructor which can throw, whatever creates the servers  either wraps the constructor in try/catch if it is recoverable, or let it percolate to the outer scope if it is not.