# How to completely destroy a socket connection in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have made a chat client in linux using socket, and i wish to destroy the connection completely. Following is the relevant portions of the code:

```
int sock, connected, bytes_recieved , true = 1, pid;  
char send_data [1024] , recv_data[1024];     
struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;    
int sin_size;
label:
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("Socket");
    exit(1);
}
if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int)) == -1)
{
    perror("Setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;         
server_addr.sin_port = htons(3128);     
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))== -1)
{
    perror("Unable to bind");
    exit(1);
}
if (listen(sock, 5) == -1)
{
    perror("Listen");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nTCPServer Waiting for client on port 3128");
fflush(stdout);
connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
//necessary code
close(sock);
goto label;
```

but the close(sock) doesnot seem to close the destroy the connection completely, because after going to 'label' the code is exiting showing the error message

```
Unable to bind: Address already in use
```

That is the connection is not happening again. What can the problem be? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: What I actually want is, when I run the script from the beginning after destroying the connection, it should run as a fresh program. How can I do it?

Comment: Why are you doing that? You should loop back to just before the `accept`, not re-create the server socket.

Comment: Why do you want to close and reopen the listening socket instead of looping around `accept()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of SO_REUSEADDR (setsockopt option) - Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229860/what-is-the-meaning-of-so-reuseaddr-setsockopt-option-linux)

Comment: When I did that, I got the reply `You are connected to <ip>, <port>` which was the printf i gave to check if the connection is established or not. The connection should be established only if the client runs the program but it is established even without the client running the program on client side. What should I do now?

Comment: "I got the reply *You are connected to <ip>, <port>*" --- where from? Your code does not contain that. Please show the relevant code.

Comment: `printf("\n You are connected to %s , %d)", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));`
This is placed right below `accept()`.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `close` call only marks the TCP socket closed. It is not usable by process anymore.
But kernel may still hold some resources for a period (TIME_WAIT, 2MLS etc stuff).

Setting of SO_REUSEADDR should remove binding problems.

So be sure that value of `true` is really non-zero when calling `setsockopt` (overflow bug may overwrite it):

```
true = 1;
setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int))
```

There is `pid` variable is your code. If you use `fork` (for starting connection handling processs), then you should close `sock` also in the process which does not need it.

Answer (score 10):

First for the naming, so we all name the same things the same:

Server side:

The socket passed to `listen()` and then to `accept()` let's call the *listening* socket.
The socket returned by `accept()` let's call the *accepted* socket.

Client side:

The socket passed to `connect()` let's call the *connecting/connected* socket.

---

Regarding your issue:

To terminate the `accept()`ed connection **close the *accepted* socket** (what you call connected) by optionally first using [`shutdown()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shutdown.html) followed by [`close ()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html).

To then accept a new connection loop right back before the call to `accept()`, **do not** go via `bind()` and `listen()` again.

Only <strike>shutdown and</strike> close the *listening* socket if you want to get rid of **pending** `connect()`s issued after `accept()` returned.

Comment: The shutdown is not necessary before closing. Close implies shutdown unless the SD is shared with another process, which is not the case here. Amd you never need to shutdown the listening socket.

Comment: @user207421: Amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

The connection is still active because you forgot to close the connected socket. Closing the listening socket does not automatically close the connected socket.

```
//necessary code
close(connected);  // <---- add this line
close(sock);
goto label;
```

I am not sure though why you are getting EADDRINUSE. The code worked fine on both linux and mac os.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [shutdown(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) system call.

Comment: I have tried it but still no luck. The connection is not not getting destroyed.

Comment: Not necessary before close.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is about `SO_REUSEADDR`.

If you are the listener, and accept a connection, you must call `shutdown()` before `close()` (at least on Linux). If you just call `close()`, you will not ACK the FIN that the client is sending to close the connection, and the client may get stuck in a `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

Answer (score -3):

Well, because a connection is really closed when the other party acknowledges it or after a certain timeout. This is normal behaviour...

EDIT: I did not actually check your code but from other users' comments, you are doing something wrong...