# c custom netcat for simple webserver

Tags: c, bash, sockets, webserver, netcat

I'm trying to make copy of netcat for webserver purposes using c and bash. This is my code in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f out
mkfifo out
trap "rm -f out" EXIT

cat out | nc -l 1500 > >(
    while read line
    do
       echo $line
       # parse http request from line
       # some other things that doesnt matter

       printf "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/html\n\ntest" > out
    done


)
```

When I visit localhost:1500 it prints "test". I want to replace netcat(nc) with my own.

```
cat out | customnc -l 1500 > >(
 #
)
```

This is customnc.c

```
#include<netinet/in.h>    
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<sys/stat.h>    
#include<sys/types.h>    
#include<unistd.h>    

int main() {    
   int create_socket, new_socket;    
   socklen_t addrlen;    
   int bufsize = 1024;    
   char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);    
   struct sockaddr_in address;    

   if ((create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0){    
      printf("The socket was created\n");
   }

   address.sin_family = AF_INET;    
   address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
   address.sin_port = htons(1600);    

   if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)) == 0){    
      printf("Binding Socket\n");
   }


      if (listen(create_socket, 10) < 0) {    
         perror("server: listen");    
         exit(1);    
      }    

      if ((new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen)) < 0) {    
         perror("server: accept");    
         exit(1);    
      }    

      if (new_socket > 0){    
         printf("The Client is connected...\n");
      }

      recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);    
      printf("%s", buffer);    
      close(new_socket);    

   close(create_socket);    
   return 0;    
}
```

What's wrong with my code? When I hit localhost:1600 (customnc) it just throws an error Unable to connect.

**The problem is with sending data from bash. If I send response in customnc.c using `write`, browser will display the message, but I have to send it from bash.**

**Edit:** The real problem is that I want to parse http request in bash and send file using bash to c. So it goes like this:
 1. Bash starts c server
 2. User opens localhost in browser
 3. C will get request and sent it back to bash
 4. Bash will parse request and send response (text) to c
 5. C will receive response and send it through socket to browser
 6. C will close socket

I'm trying to implement this but I'm not able to make this bidirectional communication. Can I do it with named pipes (2)?

Comment: Maybe you close the socket too fast?

Comment: I add sleep(4) before closing socket but it does not help.

Comment: The toybox code for its netcat is pretty easy to follow: https://github.com/landley/toybox/blob/master/toys/net/netcat.c ... and its effectively public domain, so you can simply remove the code you don't need

Comment: Can you post the code you have for "# parse request and do other stuff" that you have working with `nc`?

Comment: Added. There is just a loop with reading by line.

Comment: The bash code you posted doesn't work. The `while read line` loops forever waiting for `nc` to terminate.

Comment: I wrote in comment that printf should now be insidde that loop. Updated it again with exact working code.

Comment: That will only parse the first line of the `GET` request, which probably isn't what you want. See my edit below for a working Bash script.

Comment: To clarify further, you can only print to the `out` fifo once because `cat out` will terminate when it reads EOF.

Comment: Actually it is enough for me, I want to parse just requested file (HTTP 1.1 /somefile.html ...)

Comment: Tried your example and it works. Thanks very much! I am going to study it why it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the socket before writing anything to it. You need to read the data from `stdin` and write it to the socket before closing. Try adding this just before your call to `close(new_socket);`:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    write(new_socket, &c, 1);
}
```

Here's my full code, I also added more error checks, added a call to `fflush(stdout)`, removed the `printf` calls so that they don't get parsed by the bash script, removed the unnecessary call to `malloc`, and set `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket so it can be reused quickly (see [this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651048/164344)).

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
int main()
{
    int create_socket, new_socket;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    char c;
    int true = 1;

    if ((create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(1600);

    setsockopt(create_socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int));

    if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(create_socket, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, &addrlen)) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (recv(new_socket, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s", buffer);
    fflush(stdout);

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (write(new_socket, &c, 1) < 0)
        {
            perror("server: write");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(new_socket);
    close(create_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

This works with the following bash script. Note that I added a check for a blank line, which indicates the end of the `GET` request.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f out
mkfifo out
trap "rm -f out" EXIT

cat out | ./a.out > >(
    while read line
    do
       # strip carriage return
       line=$(echo $line | tr -d '\r')
       echo $line
       if [[ $line == "" ]]; then
           # reached end of GET request
           break
       fi
    done

    printf "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/html\n\ntest" > out
)
```

If you want to fully replace the `nc` command, you'll have to do some argument parsing to get the port number (`-l`) instead of hard coding it to 1600.

Comment: it displays "test" in browser  but now I can't parse request in bash because it's not receiving any message so it's not useful for me. You fixed one thing but broke the other one