# CreateProcess occupies socket port (Only one usage of each socket address permitted) after exit

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I listen socket port 4000 in my process. I start another process using `CreateProcess` witch using another port number. after exit my process, when i try to start it again i received this error even when the child process is killed:

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

But when i start this process normally from explorer the is no conflict happens. What should i do to release the port for my usage?

Edit: 
I use this code to create the new process.

```
CreateProcessW(NULL, pwszCommandLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
              NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 
              NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

I don't wait to process finish, because this process should not exit.

Comment: Probably the answer is to be found in the code. [mcve].

Comment: The original socket is likely in the `TIME_WAIT` state. As such its bound IP/Port can't be reused for a new socket until the old socket times out and is released by the OS. Unless you use the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option on the sockets

Comment: are you start new process with inherited handles ? socket by default was inherited handle

Comment: @RbMm how can i prevent to inherit?

Comment: yes, you use `bInheritHandles = true` in call `CreateProcess` - at first - are this actually need ? if you need concrete handles to be inherit - describe it with `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` - as result only this handles will be inherited. and in call `WSASocket` - exist option `WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT` (This flag is supported from Windows 7 with SP1)

Comment: @RbMm Thank you. I was confused changing flags to handle this problem. The problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The close call only marks the TCP socket closed. It is not usable by process anymore. But kernel may still hold some resources for a period (TIME_WAIT, 2MLS etc stuff).

Setting of SO_REUSEADDR should remove binding problems.

So be sure that value of true is really non-zero when calling setsockopt (overflow bug may overwrite it):

```
true = 1;
setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int))
```

All above is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619952/how-to-completely-destroy-a-socket-connection-in-c). 
Is this helpful ?

Comment: Actually the socket being handled in another dll witch i cant change it now. is there any other solution to create process without inherit from parent?