# What is the purpose of setReuseAddress in ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple logic Java that checks if a port is already in use or not:

```
public static boolean isPortInUse(int port)
  {
    ServerSocket socket = null;
    try {
      socket = new ServerSocket(port);
      socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
      if (socket != null) {
        try {
          socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I am new to socket programming so I am not able to understand what is the use of the method `"setReuseAddress"`here. I have gone through [this link](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29) but I am not getting clarity the purpose of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This explanation is coming from TCP mechanism involving some low level socket properties and protocols, basically there is an option called SO_REUSEADDR that you define when you are creating the socket, using the method *setReuseAddress()* enable or disable this behavior.

The current explanation is very well defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229860/what-is-the-meaning-of-so-reuseaddr-setsockopt-option-linux), take a look there. Also [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29) have very good explanation

Just take as a configuration parameter that can be modified using that method.

> Enabling SO_REUSEADDR prior to binding the socket using
>   bind(SocketAddress) allows the socket to be bound even though a
>   previous connection is in a timeout state.