# Reuse address on Linux systems

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a program that runs fine on both Windows and MacOSX, but encounters the `address already used` problem on Linux (Fedora 23, to be specific). The issue turns out to be that I'm trying to construct two `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` objects on the same port, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6. The signature of the constructor used is as follows (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor.html)):

```
basic_socket_acceptor(
    boost::asio::io_service & io_service,
    const endpoint_type & endpoint,
    bool reuse_addr = true);
```

Note the `reuse_addr` parameter. I expect it to address specifically the `address already used` problem. Alas, it does not work on Linux. Any explanation why?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Then, what is the use of `SO_REUSEADDR` on Linux, when you actually cannot reuse any address with it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3233022/562566

Comment: So it's not what you think. Also I'm not so sure that your question should have been closed as a duplicate, because I don't think your problem is really even anything to do with reuse address. Query the TCP table on your linux system and on windows. I bet you have some service bound to port 23 on your linux box. Unless writing for a specific protocol or you have other strong reasons, allow the system to assign your application a port by supplying 0 as an argument so the OS will fetch you an available ephemeral port.

Comment: I voted to reopen because your real question/problem is that you have boost-asio based software failing on linux. There's an issue not related to `reuse_addr`. I suggest editing your question so it's focus is on resolving your issue, not asking what gives about `reuse_addr`. Post an sscce while you're at it.

Comment: btw for querying, go to console, use variations of netstat like `netstat -ano`.