# socat port forwarding for https

Tags: https, forwarding, socat

I can use `socat` for the port forwarding like this:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080 TCP4:123.456.789.12:80
```

In this case, it works perfectly: all `http`-requests to `localhost:8080` will be redirected to `123.456.789.12:80`.

But how can I use such forwarding for `https`-requests?

**UPDATE:** I need a single `socat` process between Firefox and remote server. `socat` is just a forwarder (proxy redirector), nothing more. Something like this:

```
Firefox -> socat -> server
       ------------>
           https
```

Comment: Did you try [this recipe](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html)?

Comment: I have no two `socat`, but one `socat` and Firefox. So I don't understand that recipe...

Comment: I just have to redirect `https`-requests from Firefox (via `socat`) to remote server. `ssl` connection should be between Firefox and server, `socat` is just a redirector, nothing more. When I try this command `socat TCP-LISTEN:8081,fork,reuseaddr OPENSSL:123.456.789.123:80,verify=0`, I got an error "error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol".

Comment: I misread your question the first time. Does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I need single `socat` process, not two ones. `Firefox` -> `socat` -> `server`.

Answer (score 32):

Normally https servers run on port 443, so maybe that is your issue?

Trying to browse through socat to google.com with https works, albeit with an SSL certificate warning:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr TCP:google.com:443
```

(use `fork` and `reuseaddr` to allow multiple connections and fast ip:port reuse, but [beaware of the caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233022/1331399)).

Now you can access https at google from a browser, just go to https://localhost:8080.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't fit in my task. I *do* need a secure connection (ideally without any SSL certificate warnings)! Firefox should establish such secure connection with remote server via `socat` as if there's no `socat`. `socat` is just a forwarder (redirector), nothing more.

Comment: @DenisShevchenko: As far as I know, you will not be able to avoid the certificate warning because you are pointing your browser to the server running `socat`, which does not match the certificate. This is a design feature of the SSL protocol, to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: I use this
`socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr /dev/null`

Answer (score 12):

The browser security warning you are getting is because of the host name mismatch in the url and in the server certificate (e.g. `localhost` vs. `example.com`).

To make the forwarding work without this warning you need to put the forwarder on the same TCP port and override DNS resolution for the effected domain (i.e. make `example.com` resolve to `127.0.0.1`).

The simplest approach is as follows:

1. edit your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) and add  `example.com` domain to the localhost line (sort of howto is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/))
2. start your forwarding (beware that you need to use server IP address and not domain name as the domain name is already redirected to localhost)

   `socat TCP-LISTEN:443,fork,reuseaddr TCP:123.456.789.12:443`
3. check it is working in the browser via `https://example.com`

Do not forget to remove the domain entry from the hosts file when done experimenting.

---

If you can't ensure the same TCP port number, this approach might work as well -- but only under some conditions:

- the site is using relative paths in links (as an absolute path would use original (thus different) port number)
- there is no port number written in the server certificate (which is usually not the case)

---

Note: It is possible to setup a MITM socat proxy, but this would require adding an artificial trusted CA.

Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr ssl:google.com:443
```

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately, `socat` cannot be used for such a task. I should use the real HTTP proxy server instead of `socat`.