# How to get a socket FD according to the port occupied in Python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, subprocess

In my program, A serve-forever daemon is restarted in a subprocess.

The program itself is a web service, using port 5000 by default.

I don't know the detail of the start script of that daemon, but it seems to inherit the socket listening on port 5000.

So if I were to restart my program, I'll find that the port is already occupied by the daemon process.

Now I am considering to fine tune the subprocess function to close the inherited socket FD, but I don't know how to get the FD in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a permission issue. The subprocess is probably running as an other user and therefore you will not have access to the process. Use `sudo ps xauw |grep [processname]` to figure as under what user the daemon process is running.

Answer (score 1):

There is `close_fds` parameter (`subprocess.Popen`) that is safe to set to `True` on Unix (it is default on Python 3). Though you shouldn't need it: a [proper daemon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour) should close all open file descriptors itself before forking.

Unrelated: if you want your program to be able [to restart during the `TIME_WAIT` period; set `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3229926/4279)