# Cant make a tcp connection just one after the other

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ip

I am fairly new to socket programming. I saw a tutorial and tried implementing the programs in my Linux machine. The codes are :

CLIENT :

```
int main() {

char buf[256] = "In client";


// create the socket
int sock;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//setup an address
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);

int status  =  connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
if(status == -1)
{

        printf("There Was an error!");
}

recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

printf("\n %s \n", buf);
close(sock);

return 0;
}
```

SERVER:

```
int main() {

char server_message[256] = "You have reached the server!";

// create the server socket
int server_socket;
server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


// define the server address
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr =  INADDR_ANY;

// bind the socket to our specified IP and port
bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

listen(server_socket, 5);

int client_socket;
client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

// send the message
send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);

// close the socket
close(server_socket);

return 0;
}
```

The code is self-explanatory. When I run the server and then the client, for the first time, it works. But when I do it again, just after the previous one, the Client gives the message - `There Was an error!`, that means the connection is not happening.

Can anyone help why is this occurring?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many errors.  Not handling completely and correctly the result of system calls, assuming NUL-terminated buffers when it's not guaranteed.  The usual.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the errors @MartinJames. I want to learn how are they causing problems.

Comment: Try connecting to INADDR_LOOPBACK instead of INADDR_ANY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for errors for all system calls in your server. I'm guessing that your `bind` is failing, because the port is "already in use". The reason for this is that the connection from the previous instance of the server lingers for a while in the operating system's connection table.

You want to use `setsockopt` with `SO_REUSEADDR` to avoid the `bind` failure. Specifically, add this prior to the `bind` call.

```
int reuse = 1;
if (setsockopt(server_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
    perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
```

(And do check errors. Makes debugging these kinds of things much easier if you know when something fails. Also, use `perror` or `strerror(errno)` in order to find out exactly why it failed -- not just *that* it failed.)

Comment: This worked. What deos the `setsockopt` do? Does this enforces the bind ?

Comment: It allows the re-use of a port that still has `TIME_WAIT` connections in the OS connection table. After running your server/client once, execute `netstat -atn | grep 9002` to see the entries. Ordinarily these entries prevent re-use of that port for a time (the exact duration is OS-dependent). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233082/1076479 for more explanation

Answer (score 1):

Check out my whole code here and see how it runs.

This is the server

```
int main(){
    SOCKET s, newsocket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int receiving;
    char clientMessage[2000], *message;

    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("socker error at %d", GetLastError());
    }else{
        puts("socket created");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8080);

    if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
        printf("err at binding %d", GetLastError());
    }else{
        puts("binded.");
    }

    listen(s, 3);

    puts("listening to connections...");

    int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while((newsocket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET){
        puts("connection accepted");
        //send 
        message="hello client";
        send(newsocket, message, strlen(message), 0);
        recv(newsocket, clientMessage, 50, 0);
        puts(clientMessage);

    }

    puts("waiting for a machine");

    if(newsocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("newsocket invalid at %d", GetLastError());
    }




    getchar();
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

This is the client

```
int main(){
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("socket error At %d", GetLastError());
    }else{
        puts("socket initialised");
    }

    server.sin_port = htons(8080);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("176.40.201.72");

    printf("server values are defined.. \n");
    printf("connecting..\n");

    if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
        printf("connection error %d" , GetLastError());
    }else{
        puts("connected");
    }

    return 0;
}
```