# Testing UDP example server in `man addrinfo`

Tags: c, sockets, udp, getaddrinfo

In [`man addrinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) there is example code for an UDP server.

I compiled that code, and run it on a terminal using `a.out 9001`.

On a second terminal I run `netcat 127.0.0.1 9001`, hoping that that will open an interactive session with the local server.

And one of the times I tried it did right that, and I could write messages that would be echoed by the server, through in the first terminal the server would not print the received messages as I expected.

But all other times the netcat command just executes and nothing happens. No error message nor output.

This is what there is in the terminal:

```
jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/Documentos/C$ netcat 127.0.0.1 9000
jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/Documentos/C$ netcat 127.0.0.1 8000
hola
hola
hola
hola
test
test
do not copy me
do not copy me
^Z
[4]+  Detenido                netcat 127.0.0.1 8000
jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/Documentos/C$ netcat 127.0.0.1 9001
jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/Documentos/C$ netcat 127.0.0.1 9002
```

When I bond to 8000 is when the interactive session seemed to be working.

Also, after stopping the server I cannot run the program again using the same port.

What is going on?

Comment: You seem to have multiple problems, that really are unrelated to each other and should be asked as separate questions. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please edit your question to actually *include* the code, as well as the expected and actual output from it.

Comment: Aside from your server code, note that `netcat` assumes `TCP` by default.  You might want to try `netcat -u 127.0.0.1 9001` to force `UDP`.

Comment: @G.M. That was it! Thank you!

Comment: You might like to have look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229860/what-is-the-meaning-of-so-reuseaddr-setsockopt-option-linux

Comment: Also you probably want to implement (a more detailed) error handling and logging.